# Why do ASP.NET TreeView nodes align middle

Tags: asp.net, css, treeview

Why do ASP.NET TreeView nodes vertically align middle by default? Is there a way around it? I want to have a full page height TreeView with nodes aligning top. This simple line creates a TreeView with nodes appearing in the middle of the TreeView:

```
<asp:TreeView runat="server" ImageSet="Inbox" ID="tvMain" Height="500px" />
```

This is VS2010 + ASP.NET 4.0 if that has something to do. Plus I'm open to CSS solutions if that is what it takes.

Comment: A sample of the generated html would help us i guess!

Comment: Have you ever looked at [CSS Adapters](http://www.asp.net/CSSAdapters/TreeView.aspx)?